# Access to structure member by pointer

Tags: c

I have a structure that I pass to a function as constant pointer, my question is the following: There is a difference between those two implementations of function updatedFields:

```
typedef struct
{
    int spec[100];
    int spec1[200];
    int spec2[200];
    int spec3[500];
    int spec4[100];
    int spec5[700];
    float value[100];
    char desc[1000]:
}t_product;



void updateFields_1(t_product const* context)
{

    int i,buffer[1500];
    int * pt_int;

    pt_int = (int*)context->spec1;      
    for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = pt_int[i];
    }

    pt_int = (int*)context->spec3;        
    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = pt_int[i];
    }

    ...
}

void updateFields_2(t_product const* context)
{

    int i,buffer[1500];

    for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = context->spec1[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = context->spec3[i];
    }

    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    t_product prod;

    /* Initialisation of the structure */
    ...

    updateField(&prod);

}
```

I mean, there is any advantages to use pointer to member of a struct (pointer to the arrays) instead of accessing directly to the member of struture.

It's probably a dumb question but I don't know if the access of a struct member "costs" more operations.

Comment: Please lose the cast in `pt_int = (int*)context->spec3;`. The types are already compatible and gratuitous casting can hide errors.

Comment: Do you actually need the `for` loop? I think, for individual members (array type), you can directly go for `memcpy()`, isn't it?

Comment: It's *int* main, not void main. I took the liberty to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't ever cost more in your case. Even without optimization. Actually your `pt_int` example is likely to be slightly worse if you don't enable optimizations.

This is because `context->spec3[i]` isn't dereferencing more pointers than `pt_int[i]`. `pt_int[i]` is just a pointer plus an offset, so the access can be written as `@(ptr_int + 4*i)`. In `context->spec3[i]`, it could look like there is one more pointer dereferenced, but it isn't the case. `spec3` isn't a value in `context`, it's just an offset from context. The address you access will therefore be `@(context + 2000 + 4*i)`. There is only one pointer access.

Now you can wonder if `@(context + 2000 + 4*i)` costs more than `@(ptr_int + 4*i)`. It doesn't, because most architectures, including x86, AMD64 and ARM (that is, 100% of personal devices), have instructions to do accesses with constant offsets. Also, the difference can disappear at soon as you enable trivial optimizations, because `context + 2000` can be converted to a single `context_2000` (but compilers won't actually do that, since it can only worsen performances).

Comment: Is it really safe to say that `@(context + 2000 + 4*i)` and `@(ptr_int + 4*i)` both cost the same, just because there is an *instruction to do accesses with constant offsets*?

Comment: @mastov Yes, because it means it's the same instruction for both, and an offset doesn't make these instructions more costly (offsets are trivial to compute).

Answer (score 1):

It does cost more (it has to de-reference the original pointer each iteration), but the cost is probably small, and a halfway decent compiler will make this optimization for you.